# updating catalina.properties file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have one file (for example: test.txt), this file contains some lines and for example one line is: abcd=/usr/home where /usr/home could be different but abcd= is the same in all case,

so could someone help me in writing shell command for deleting the "/usr/home" from a line but not "abcd="

really appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `abcd` itself doesn't contain `=` this will work:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "="; OFS = "=" } $1 == "abcd" { print $1, "new value"; next } 1' < test.txt > test_new.txt
```

Input:

```
abcd=/usr/home
efgh=something else
```

Output:

```
abcd=new value
efgh=something else
```

Answer (score 1):

Let prop_file is name of your property file. e.g. text.txt and you want to replace abcd= /usr/home with abcd=newcontent

File prop_file contains the following line with other contents.

```
abcd=/usr/home
```

Make shell sript file startup.sh

Shell script startup.sh contains

```
sed "s/abcd=.*/abcd=$1/g" prop_file > tmp
mv tmp prop_file
```

Execute

```
sh startup.sh newcontent
```

Comment: echo "$shared.loader" | sed 's/=.*//'
worked like charm......thanks all for your responses.